# Windows 10 SDK 1.3 visual designer hangs and throws error

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I updated VS 2015 to Update 2 along with the 1.3 SDK, now when I open a xaml file the designer seems to be working hard and hanging all of VS. When closing shows there was an exception, checking the log it shows this:

Any workaround yet?

```
<entry>
<record>919</record>
<time>2016/04/05 16:54:19.061</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.HostProject.get_CodeDocumentTypeIdentifier()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Extensions.HostExtensions.IsCPlusPlusProject(IHostProject project)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Metadata.ManagedTypeResolverService.GetTypeResolver(IHostProject hostProject)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.GetFileContextScope(String fileName, IVsTextLines textLines, IXamlFileInformationContext&amp; fileContext)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextView view)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlSource.BeginParse(Int32 line, Int32 idx, TokenInfo info, ParseReason reason, IVsTextView view, ParseResultHandler callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ViewFilter.GetDataTipText(TextSpan[] aspan, String&amp; textValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(IQuickInfoSession session, TextSpan[] dataBufferTextSpan, String&amp; tipText)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession session, IList`1 qiContent, ITrackingSpan&amp; applicableToSpan)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()</description>
```

This one shows too:

```
  <entry>
<record>917</record>
<time>2016/04/05 16:52:01.816</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>XAML Designer</source>
<description>XAML Designer Exception&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Type: System.ArgumentNullException&#x000D;&#x000A;Message: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: source&#x000D;&#x000A;Stack:&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.WindowsXamlManifestUtility.GenerateExtensionsXml(IHostProject project, ManifestSchema schema)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.WindowsXamlManifestUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass33_0.&lt;GenerateManifestContents&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass48_0`1.&lt;MarshalIn&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean waitingInExternalCall)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call call)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.DirectInvoke(Boolean inbound, Action action, Int32 sourceApartmentId, Int32 targetApartmentId, Int32 originId, WaitHandle aborted)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.DirectInvokeInbound(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.WindowsXamlManifestUtility.GenerateManifestContents(IEnumerable`1 dependencyIdentifiers, IHostProject project, String&amp; packageId)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.WindowsXamlAppPackage.CreateManifestFile()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackage.InitializeApplication()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.WindowsXamlAppPackage.CreateOrRecover(IHostProject project, IHostProjectService projectService, IHostPlatformService platformService, IHostShadowCopyService shadowCopyService, PackageService packageService, IHostFileChangeWatcherService fileChangeWatcherService, String frameworkPackagePath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.PackageService.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass10_0.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__0(IHostProject project, IHostProjectService projectService, IHostPlatformService platformService, IHostShadowCopyService shadowCopyService)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.PackageService.CreateAppPackage(IHostProject hostProject)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.PackageService.GetOrCreateAppPackage(IHostProject project, Boolean&amp; isCreated)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.HostProject.get_AppPackage()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.InitializePrimaryProject(IHostProject project)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.InitializeLanguageContextComponents(IHostProject project)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
```

When I create a new project the designer works fine but I get the following error on project properties on Application tab:

Property accessor 'TargetDescriptions' on object 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectFlavoring.Automation.Project.CommonProjectExtender' threw the following exception:'Value cannot be null.

This happens either if I keep min version 10.0.10240 or leave min as 10586

Removing SDK 10240 worked to solve the designer issue in my "old" project, still the error at the project properties happens

**UPDATE:**

I completely uninstalled the Windows 10 SDK, along with the 8.1 SDK, then reinstalled only 10 SDK (10586) using the VS installer from the dev site https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads

And it's worse now, I can't compile, the application tab in properties now says this:

An error occurred trying to load the page.
InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Also when I try to create a new Blank Universal app I get the following message:
"Could not find a suitable SDK to target"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only thing that worked was uninstalling all standalone Windows SDKs, from 10586.11, 10586.15 and before, then reinstalling the 10586.15 again, this worked finally, just in case someone gets into this